# Changing expiry date in SugarCRM workflow do net send a mail to test administrator

Tags: php, workflow, sugarcrm

I have a workflow defined in SugarCRM defined on Tasks modules it works perfectly when i create a new task, automatically a mail will be send to the Test Administrator. But if i edit the same task or any other previously defined task to increase the expiry date no mail is send to the Test Administrator. Can you explain it is the default behaviour of SugarCRM or i am getting wrong at some point. My scheduler is functioning properly on the interval of every 5 minutes.

For further details please examine the image provided below:

[image: Workflow Definition Screen]

Any help in this regard will be appreciated

Comment: Please message me with your Company name and I can have our support team follow up with you. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot jmertic for your coperation infact that was the problem with cron  in Linux i.e. the cron had not launched in time automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the version of Sugar in use. Some versions have a bug where Time-elapsed workflow are not triggered correctly.